# Java - Program with KeyListener isn't working

Tags: java, swing, jframe, keylistener

Main problem: When I created a norwegian calculator using the `KeyListener`, it didn't work properly.

I've added a call to the JFrame's `addKeyListener()` method and I've implemented the `KeyListener` interface and everything. But it still doesn't work. I apologize for poor code.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**CODE:**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;  
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.Random;


public class miniräknare extends JFrame implements KeyListener {
public static int answer = 0;
public JLabel lblRandomnum;
public static int answer2 = 0;
public static boolean flip = true;
public static JLabel lblOutput;
Random myRandom = new Random();
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new miniräknare();

}


public miniräknare() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 300, 600);
    setResizable(false);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    lblOutput = new JLabel("" + answer);
    lblOutput.setBounds(35, 33, 222, 37);
    getContentPane().add(lblOutput);
    JButton button = new JButton("1");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        increment(1);
        lblRandomnum.setText("");
        }
    });
    button.setBounds(35, 111, 75, 75);
    getContentPane().add(button);

    JButton button_1 = new JButton("2");
    button_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            increment(2);
            lblRandomnum.setText("");
        }
    });
    button_1.setBounds(109, 111, 75, 75);
    getContentPane().add(button_1);

    JButton button_2 = new JButton("3");
    button_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            increment(3);
            lblRandomnum.setText("");
        }
    });
    button_2.setBounds(182, 111, 75, 75);
    getContentPane().add(button_2);

    JButton button_3 = new JButton("4");
    button_3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            increment(4);
            lblRandomnum.setText("");
        }
    });
    button_3.setBounds(35, 184, 75, 75);
    getContentPane().add(button_3);

    JButton button_4 = new JButton("5");
    button_4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            increment(5);
            lblRandomnum.setText("");
        }
    });
    button_4.setBounds(109, 184, 75, 75);
    getContentPane().add(button_4);

    JButton button_5 = new JButton("6");
    button_5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        increment(6);
        lblRandomnum.setText("");
        }
    });
    button_5.setBounds(182, 184, 75, 75);
    getContentPane().add(button_5);

    JButton button_6 = new JButton("7");
    button_6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            increment(7);
            lblRandomnum.setText("");
        }
    });
    button_6.setBounds(35, 257, 75, 75);
    getContentPane().add(button_6);

    JButton button_7 = new JButton("8");
    button_7.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            increment(8);
            lblRandomnum.setText("");
        }
    });
    button_7.setBounds(109, 257, 75, 75);
    getContentPane().add(button_7);

    JButton button_8 = new JButton("0");
    button_8.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            increment(0);
            lblRandomnum.setText("");
        }
    });
    button_8.setBounds(109, 331, 75, 75);
    getContentPane().add(button_8);

    JButton button_9 = new JButton("9");
    button_9.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            increment(9);
            lblRandomnum.setText("");
        }
    });
    button_9.setBounds(182, 257, 75, 75);
    getContentPane().add(button_9);

    JButton btnC = new JButton("C");
    btnC.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            answer = 0;
            answer2 = 0;
            flip = true;
            lblOutput.setText("" + answer);
            lblRandomnum.setText("");
        }
    });
    btnC.setBounds(35, 331, 75, 75);
    getContentPane().add(btnC);

    JButton button_10 = new JButton("=");
    button_10.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        lblOutput.setText("tänker.........");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        lblOutput.setText("Detta tal är för advancerat :-(");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        lblRandomnum.setText("Men, jag tror det blir " + myRandom.nextInt(100000));
        }
    });
    button_10.setBounds(182, 331, 75, 75);
    getContentPane().add(button_10);

    JButton button_11 = new JButton("+");
    button_11.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if((lblOutput.getText().endsWith("+")) || (lblOutput.getText().endsWith("-")) || (lblOutput.getText().endsWith("x")) || (lblOutput.getText().endsWith("%"))) {
                lblOutput.setText("" + answer + "+");
            }
            else lblOutput.setText(lblOutput.getText() + "+");
            if(flip) {
                lblOutput.setText("+");
                flip = false;
            }
            else if(!flip) {
                flip = true;
            }
        }
    });
    button_11.setBounds(35, 405, 75, 75);
    getContentPane().add(button_11);

    JButton button_12 = new JButton("-");
    button_12.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if((lblOutput.getText().endsWith("+")) || (lblOutput.getText().endsWith("-")) || (lblOutput.getText().endsWith("x")) || (lblOutput.getText().endsWith("%"))) {
                lblOutput.setText("" + answer + "-");
            }
            else lblOutput.setText(lblOutput.getText() + "-");
            if(flip) {
                lblOutput.setText("-");
                flip = false;
            }
            else if(!flip) {
                flip = true;
            }
        }
    });
    button_12.setBounds(109, 405, 75, 75);
    getContentPane().add(button_12);

    JButton btnX = new JButton("X");
    btnX.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if((lblOutput.getText().endsWith("+")) || (lblOutput.getText().endsWith("-")) || (lblOutput.getText().endsWith("x")) || (lblOutput.getText().endsWith("%"))) {
                lblOutput.setText("" + answer + "x");
            }
            else lblOutput.setText(lblOutput.getText() + "x");
            if(flip) {
                lblOutput.setText("x");
                flip = false;
            }
            else if(!flip) {
                flip = true;
            }
        }
    });
    btnX.setBounds(182, 405, 75, 75);
    getContentPane().add(btnX);

    JButton button_13 = new JButton("%");
    button_13.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if((lblOutput.getText().endsWith("+")) || (lblOutput.getText().endsWith("-")) || (lblOutput.getText().endsWith("x")) || (lblOutput.getText().endsWith("%"))) {
                lblOutput.setText("" + answer + "%");
            }
            else lblOutput.setText(lblOutput.getText() + "%");
            if(flip) {
                lblOutput.setText("%");
                flip = false;
            }
            else if(!flip) {
                flip = true;
            }
        }
    });
    button_13.setBounds(109, 479, 75, 75);
    getContentPane().add(button_13);

    lblRandomnum = new JLabel("randomnum");
    lblRandomnum.setBounds(45, 82, 212, 16);
    getContentPane().add(lblRandomnum);
    lblRandomnum.setText("");
    setVisible(true);
    setTitle("norsk miniräknare");
    addKeyListener(this);
}

public static void increment(int i) {
    if(flip) {
    String s = "" + answer;
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(s);
    if(s.startsWith("0")) {
        answer = i;
    } else {
    str.insert(s.length(), "" + i);
    s = str.toString(); 

    if(s.length() != 10) answer = Integer.parseInt(s);
    }
    lblOutput.setText("" + answer);
    }
    if(!flip) {
        String s = "" + answer2;
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(s);
        if(s.startsWith("0")) {
            answer2 = i;
        } else {
        str.insert(s.length(), "" + i);
        s = str.toString();
        answer2 = Integer.parseInt(s);
        }
        lblOutput.setText("" + answer2);
        }
}


@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("lol");
    int KeyCode = e.getKeyCode();
    if(KeyCode == KeyEvent.VK_0) increment(0);
    if(KeyCode == KeyEvent.VK_1) increment(1);
    if(KeyCode == KeyEvent.VK_2) increment(2);
    if(KeyCode == KeyEvent.VK_3) increment(3);
    if(KeyCode == KeyEvent.VK_4) increment(4);
    if(KeyCode == KeyEvent.VK_5) increment(5);
    if(KeyCode == KeyEvent.VK_6) increment(6);
    if(KeyCode == KeyEvent.VK_7) increment(7);
    if(KeyCode == KeyEvent.VK_8) increment(8);
    if(KeyCode == KeyEvent.VK_9) increment(9);
}


@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("trololol");

}


@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("ofta");
}
}
```

Comment: The string "still doesn't work" is not a built-in error message in any programming language of which I'm aware.

Comment: In other words, please explain the details of your problem. Just how isn't your code working?

Answer (score 2):

Don't add a KeyListener to a JFrame. KeyListeners only work if they are added to a component that has focus, and that is hardly ever the JFrame. In fact with Swing applications, you should avoid using KeyListeners altogether and instead use Key Bindings since these get around the focus problem and allow you to use re-usable Actions.

Please check out the Key Bindings tutorial: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

Also as an aside: you shouldn't be using null layout and set bounds as it makes for a very difficult program to debug and extend. Instead consider using an array of JButtons placed into your GUI using layout managers. A GridLayout would work well for the JPanel that holds your JButtons.